# Python : filter list items from list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
 names = ['vapp1', 'vapp3', 'vapp4', 'vapp2']

vapps = [{'name':'vapp2', 'ip': '11.21.18.24', 'obj': 'obj523'}, {'name':'vapp3', 'ip': '11.21.18.27', 'obj': 'obj234'}, {'name':'vapp5', 'ip': '11.21.18.25', 'obj': 'obj246'}]


result = [vapp for vapp in vapps if vapp['name'] in names]
print result
```

Using this list/dict comprehension I am getting what I want in result. But I also want to print that `vapp1` & `vapp4` are not there in `vapps` .

What is the most efficient way ? or How to avoid extra looping to achieve all of this so that I will get a filtered list of dictionary whose names are common in the list `names`. And also I can print those names which are not there.

Comment: Can you be a little clear on your question? `result = [vapp for vapp in vapps if vapp['name'] in names]` will print those which are there (your code itself) and `result = [vapp for vapp in vapps if vapp['name'] not in names]` will print what is not there (which is what you want). Elaborate on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* abuse the short-circuiting of `and` like so:

```
>>> result = [vapp for vapp in vapps if
...           vapp['name'] in names and
...           (names.remove(vapp['name']) or 1)]
>>> names # now contains names not found in vapps
['vapp1', 'vapp4']
```

This will yield the same result list as before, and modifies `names` so it removes found vapp names as a side effect.

This works because the `and` clause is only evaluated when the first part of the statement (`vapp['name'] in names`) is `True`. The `or 1` part is needed because `.remove()` yields `None`, which is `False` in a boolean context.

List comprehensions with side effects are generally discouraged as bad style, though - and your `names` list will get modified, so better save a copy if you need it again.

Generally, do not worry about performance, and just use two loops - or write it out in a readable, classic loop.

Comment: You are right ! The answer is "Generally, do not worry about performance, and just use two loops - or write it out in a readable, classic loop."

Answer (score 1):

You could do following

just using some set properties we can get it

> > > vapps_names = [vapp['name'] for vapp in vapps]

now
Values not in vapps but in names

> > > not_in_vapps = set(names) - set(vapps_names)
> > >
> > > {'vapp1', 'vapp4'}

Values in names not in vapps

> > > not_in_names = set(vapps_names) - set(names)
> > >
> > > {'vapp5'}